# Multiple Windows In ASP.NET Core Blazor

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am learning Blazor from a WinForms background. In Winforms I used to create a new form perhaps on a click of a button to display some info or a map then drag it to a second monitor.Can I achieve the same with a blazor app. I see many tutorials on dialogs but I believe that I am correct in thinking that this is not what I am looking for in that you cant move a dialog to diffrent part of the screen or 2nd monitor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blazor is a web app technology, so you can't break out of the context of the tab (or tabs) in the same way that you can with WinForms by opening a new form, even dialogs will remain inside the context of the current tab.

I would suggest the following:

- Use JS Interop to open a new tab targeting the component that you want opened separate from the current location
- Drag that tab onto another monitor.

  ```
    @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

    public async Task OpenInNewTab(string url)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", url, "_blank");
    }
  ```

Comment: That would not resolve the issue, as this is like opening a second instance of the app.... The two tabs won't be sharing any app state ... Am I correct ?

Comment: It doesn't need to share any state if you are trying to open something in a separate tab. Blazor is still a web technology and it's easier to reason about if you think about it in terms of requests and not a permanent state from the moment the application is opened.